# Setting up a WindowsHook in Python (ctypes, Windows API)

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I am trying to globally track the mouse with a Python (3.4.3) background app (in Windows 7/8). This involves setting up a WindowsHook which should return me a valid handle to that specific hook - but my handle is always 0.

Tracking only the mouse position is very easy with `GetCursorPos` (as an alternative `GetCursorInfo` works as well):

```py
from ctypes.wintypes import *
ppoint = ctypes.pointer(POINT())
ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ppoint)
print('({}, {})'.format(ppoint[0].x, ppoint[0].y))
```

Also convenient to track only the position is [`GetMouseMovePointsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646259(v=vs.85).aspx), which tracks the last 64 mouse positions:

```py
from ctypes.wintypes import *

# some additional types and structs
ULONG_PTR = ctypes.c_ulong
class MOUSEMOVEPOINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ctypes.c_int),
        ("y", ctypes.c_int),
        ("time", DWORD),
        ("dwExtraInfo", ULONG_PTR)
    ]
GMMP_USE_DISPLAY_POINTS = 1

# get initial tracking point
ppoint = ctypes.pointer(POINT())
ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ppoint)
point = MOUSEMOVEPOINT(ppoint[0].x,ppoint[0].y)

# track last X points
number_mouse_points = 64
points = (MOUSEMOVEPOINT * number_mouse_points)()
ctypes.windll.user32.GetMouseMovePointsEx(ctypes.sizeof(MOUSEMOVEPOINT), 
    ctypes.pointer(point), ctypes.pointer(points), number_mouse_points, 
    GMMP_USE_DISPLAY_POINTS)

# print results
for point in points:
    print('({}, {})'.format(point.x, point.y))
```

However I want to be able to also track clicks, drags, etc.
A good solution seems to be the [`LowLevelMouseProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx). (There might be another way yet to be explored: [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536(VS.85).aspx))

To be able to use the LowLevelMouseProc the documentation tells us to use [`SetWindowsHookEx(W/A)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), which is also covered in [various](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx) (C++) [tutorials](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804) (C#), as well as some interesting [projects](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/blob/913b710bc3881d9fffe8c9003786f99e70dcc90c/MouseKeyHook/WinApi/HookHelper.cs) (also C#).

The documentation defines it in C++ as follows:

```cpp
HHOOK WINAPI SetWindowsHookEx(
  _In_ int       idHook,
  _In_ HOOKPROC  lpfn,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hMod,
  _In_ DWORD     dwThreadId
);
```

Where the following should be the correct values for me in python:

- `idHook`: [`WH_MOUSE_LL = 14`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)
- `hMod`: `HINSTANCE(0)` (basically a null pointer)
- `dwThreadId`: `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId()`

And for the `lpfn` I need some callback implementing the [`LowLevelMouseProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx), here `LLMouseProc`:

```py
def _LLMouseProc (nCode, wParam, lParam):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(None, nCode, wParam, lParam)
LLMouseProcCB = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, ctypes.c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)
LLMouseProc = LLMouseProcCB(_LLMouseProc)
```

Putting it all together I expected this to work:

```py
from ctypes.wintypes import *

LONG_PTR = ctypes.c_long
LRESULT = LONG_PTR
WH_MOUSE_LL = 14

def _LLMouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    print("_LLMouseProc({!s}, {!s}, {!s})".format(nCode, wParam, lParam))
    return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(None, nCode, wParam, lParam)
LLMouseProcCB = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, ctypes.c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)
LLMouseProc = LLMouseProcCB(_LLMouseProc)

threadId = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId()

# register callback as hook
print('hook = SetWindowsHookExW({!s}, {!s}, {!s}, {!s})'.format(WH_MOUSE_LL, LLMouseProc,
    HINSTANCE(0), threadId))
hook = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE_LL, LLMouseProc, 
    HINSTANCE(0), threadId)
print('Hook: {}'.format(hook))

import time
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

But the output reveals that `hook == 0`:

```
hook = SetWindowsHookExW(14, <CFunctionType object at 0x026183F0>, c_void_p(None), 5700)
Hook: 0
```

I think that maybe the last parameter of the callback function, name `lParam` is not really correct as LPARAM (which is `ctypes.c_long`), since what I assume is really expected is a pointer to this struct:

```py
class MSLLHOOKSTRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("pt", POINT),
        ("mouseData", DWORD),
        ("flags", DWORD),
        ("time", DWORD),
        ("dwExtraInfo", ULONG_PTR)
    ]
```

But changing the signature to `LLMouseProcCB = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, ctypes.c_int, WPARAM, ctypes.POINTER(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT))` does not solve the problem, I still have a hook of 0.

Is this the right approach of tracking the mouse? What do I need to change to be able to correctly register hooks with Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check `GetLastError` you should discover that the error is `ERROR_GLOBAL_ONLY_HOOK` (1429), i.e. `WH_MOUSE_LL` requires setting a global hook. The `dwThreadId` parameter is for setting a local hook. Fortunately `WH_MOUSE_LL` is unusual in that the global hook callback can be any function in the hooking process instead of having to be defined in a DLL, i.e. `hMod` can be `NULL`.

Pay attention to the calling convention if you need to support 32-bit Windows. The 32-bit Windows API generally requires `stdcall` (callee stack cleanup), so the callback needs to be defined via `WINFUNCTYPE` instead of `CFUNCTYPE`.

Another issue is that your code lacks a message loop. The thread that sets the hook needs to run a message loop in order to dispatch the message to the callback. In the example below I use a dedicated thread for this message loop. The thread sets the hook and enters a loop that only breaks on error or when a `WM_QUIT` message is posted. When the user enters `Ctrl+C`, I call `PostThreadMessageW` to gracefully exit.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

user32 = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

HC_ACTION = 0
WH_MOUSE_LL = 14

WM_QUIT        = 0x0012
WM_MOUSEMOVE   = 0x0200
WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201
WM_LBUTTONUP   = 0x0202
WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204
WM_RBUTTONUP   = 0x0205
WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207
WM_MBUTTONUP   = 0x0208
WM_MOUSEWHEEL  = 0x020A
WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E

MSG_TEXT = {WM_MOUSEMOVE:   'WM_MOUSEMOVE',
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN: 'WM_LBUTTONDOWN',
            WM_LBUTTONUP:   'WM_LBUTTONUP',
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN: 'WM_RBUTTONDOWN',
            WM_RBUTTONUP:   'WM_RBUTTONUP',
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN: 'WM_MBUTTONDOWN',
            WM_MBUTTONUP:   'WM_MBUTTONUP',
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL:  'WM_MOUSEWHEEL',
            WM_MOUSEHWHEEL: 'WM_MOUSEHWHEEL'}

ULONG_PTR = WPARAM
LRESULT = LPARAM
LPMSG = POINTER(MSG)

HOOKPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)
LowLevelMouseProc = HOOKPROC

class MSLLHOOKSTRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('pt',          POINT),
                ('mouseData',   DWORD),
                ('flags',       DWORD),
                ('time',        DWORD),
                ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR))

LPMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = POINTER(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)

def errcheck_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    return args

user32.SetWindowsHookExW.errcheck = errcheck_bool
user32.SetWindowsHookExW.restype = HHOOK
user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (c_int,     # _In_ idHook
                                     HOOKPROC,  # _In_ lpfn
                                     HINSTANCE, # _In_ hMod
                                     DWORD)     # _In_ dwThreadId

user32.CallNextHookEx.restype = LRESULT
user32.CallNextHookEx.argtypes = (HHOOK,  # _In_opt_ hhk
                                  c_int,  # _In_     nCode
                                  WPARAM, # _In_     wParam
                                  LPARAM) # _In_     lParam

user32.GetMessageW.argtypes = (LPMSG, # _Out_    lpMsg
                               HWND,  # _In_opt_ hWnd
                               UINT,  # _In_     wMsgFilterMin
                               UINT)  # _In_     wMsgFilterMax

user32.TranslateMessage.argtypes = (LPMSG,)
user32.DispatchMessageW.argtypes = (LPMSG,)

@LowLevelMouseProc
def LLMouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    msg = cast(lParam, LPMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)[0]
    if nCode == HC_ACTION:
        msgid = MSG_TEXT.get(wParam, str(wParam))
        msg = ((msg.pt.x, msg.pt.y),
                msg.mouseData, msg.flags,
                msg.time, msg.dwExtraInfo)
        print('{:15s}: {}'.format(msgid, msg))
    return user32.CallNextHookEx(None, nCode, wParam, lParam)

def mouse_msg_loop():
    hHook = user32.SetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE_LL, LLMouseProc, None, 0)
    msg = MSG()
    while True:
        bRet = user32.GetMessageW(byref(msg), None, 0, 0)
        if not bRet:
            break
        if bRet == -1:
            raise WinError(get_last_error())
        user32.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
        user32.DispatchMessageW(byref(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    import threading
    t = threading.Thread(target=mouse_msg_loop)
    t.start()
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            user32.PostThreadMessageW(t.ident, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
            break
```

Comment: I can't even tell how much I learned from this answer. Lots of interestings things about the WinAPI, and I had to read up on python decorators. What I don't exactly understand is why WH_MOUSE_LL is so special in terms of that you don't need to subscribe it to a DLL - I understood it from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx that it is possible with all to either hook them to the current thread or a DLL. It seemed to me the only difference was that some hooks only work on a global basis in terms of the events they get?

Comment: The [`LowLevelMouseProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986) documentation states that the hook is called in the "context of the thread that installed it" by "sending a message to the thread". In other cases, if inter-thread messaging isn't used or can't be used, then the DLL that has the hook procedure needs to be loaded beforehand (except if it can't be loaded, e.g. a 32-bit DLL can't be loaded in a 64-bit process; how this works is discussed in the `SetWindowsHookEx` docs).

Comment: How do we pass a hookproc that we've already got in a C Dll?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047858/pass-a-function-pointer-from-a-c-dll-to-a-c-dll

Answer (score 1):

## A simplified version of the accepted answer

**Note**: `pip install pywin32` first.

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/10 22:27

from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, c_int, Structure, cast, POINTER, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import LPARAM, WPARAM, DWORD, PULONG, LONG

import win32con
import win32gui


def genStruct(name="Structure", **kwargs):
    return type(name, (Structure,), dict(
        _fields_=list(kwargs.items()),
        __str__=lambda self: "%s(%s)" % (name, ",".join("%s=%s" % (k, getattr(self, k)) for k in kwargs))
    ))


@WINFUNCTYPE(LPARAM, c_int, WPARAM, LPARAM)
def hookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    msg = cast(lParam, POINTER(HookStruct))[0]
    print(msgDict[wParam], msg)
    return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(None, nCode, WPARAM(wParam), LPARAM(lParam))


HookStruct = genStruct(
    "Hook", pt=genStruct("Point", x=LONG, y=LONG), mouseData=DWORD, flags=DWORD, time=DWORD, dwExtraInfo=PULONG)
msgDict = {v: k for k, v in win32con.__dict__.items() if k.startswith("WM_")}
windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, hookProc, None, 0)
win32gui.PumpMessages()
```

### Sample Output

```
WM_MOUSEMOVE Hook(pt=Point(x=50,y=702),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134468,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_MOUSEMOVE Hook(pt=Point(x=49,y=704),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134484,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_MOUSEMOVE Hook(pt=Point(x=49,y=705),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134484,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_MOUSEMOVE Hook(pt=Point(x=49,y=705),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134500,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_MOUSEMOVE Hook(pt=Point(x=49,y=706),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134500,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_MOUSEMOVE Hook(pt=Point(x=48,y=707),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134515,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_LBUTTONDOWN Hook(pt=Point(x=48,y=707),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134593,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
WM_LBUTTONUP Hook(pt=Point(x=48,y=707),mouseData=0,flags=0,time=343134671,dwExtraInfo=<ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_ulong object at 0x000001A466CDF8C8>)
```