# Pass a function pointer from a C Dll to a C Dll

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use the Windows function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa to register a global hook.

I have created a hook procedure in a C++ Dll and have tested it with a executable written in C++ which calls SetWindowsHookEx, and it seems to work fine.

Here is a snippet of the important code in my C++ Dll:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "FSHooksLib.h"
#include "global.h"

typedef void (*callback_function)(int);
callback_function g_callback = nullptr;
HHOOK g_hook = nullptr;

extern "C" FSHOOKS_API void Init()
{
    if (g_log)
    {
        g_log.close();
    }

    g_log.open("hookslog.txt", std::ofstream::out);
    g_log << "FSHooksLib has been initialized" << std::endl;
}

extern "C" FSHOOKS_API void Release()
{
    if (g_log)
    {
        g_log << "FSHooksLib has been releaseded" << std::endl;
        g_log.close();
    }
}

extern "C" FSHOOKS_API void SetCallback(callback_function callback)
{
    g_callback = callback;
    g_log << "Callback has been set" << std::endl;
}

extern "C" FSHOOKS_API LRESULT HookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code != HC_ACTION)
        return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, code, wParam, lParam);

    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* info = reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
    POINT point = info->pt;
    DWORD flags = info->flags;
    bool injected = flags & LLMHF_INJECTED;
    bool lower_injected = flags & LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED;
    DWORD time = info->time;

    switch (wParam)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        g_log << "Received a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message with injected=" << injected << std::endl;

        if (g_callback)
        {
            g_callback(g_numProcesses);
        }
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        g_log << "Received a WM_LBUTTONUP message with injected=" << injected << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Here is what the Injector program written in C++ looks like:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("FSHooks.dll");
    if (!hMod)
    {
        std::cerr << "Count not load the FSHooks library" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    FARPROC fn_init = GetProcAddress(hMod, "Init");
    if (!fn_init)
    {
        std::cerr << "Count not get the 'Init' function from FSHooks library" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    FARPROC fn_release = GetProcAddress(hMod, "Release");
    if (!fn_release)
    {
        std::cerr << "Count not get the 'Release' function from FSHooks library" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    HOOKPROC fn_hook = reinterpret_cast<HOOKPROC>(GetProcAddress(hMod, "HookProc"));
    if (!fn_hook)
    {
        std::cerr << "Count not get the 'HookProc' function from FSHooks library" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, fn_hook, hMod, 0);
    if (!hook)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to SetWindowsHookEx" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    fn_init();

    MSG msg;
    // TODO - We will need some manner of signal to terminate
    //        This is just a quick and dirty example program
    while (true)
    {
        GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    fn_release();
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
    return 0;
}
```

So now, if I want to try and do the same thing the injector does, from my python application. I am stuck on how to pass the hook procedure argument.

I have the following code in my wx window code to initialize the hook:

```
import os.path
import threading
import win32con
import win32api
import wx
from ctypes import *


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(800, 600))
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        menu_file = wx.Menu()
        menu_item_exit = menu_file.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", " Terminate the program")

        menu_help = wx.Menu()
        menu_item_about = menu_help.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About", " Information about this program")

        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu_bar.Append(menu_file, "&File")
        menu_bar.Append(menu_help, "&Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_about, menu_item_about)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_exit, menu_item_exit)

        self.Show(True)

    def on_about(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A window to test Windows Hooks", "About Test Windows Hooks",
                               wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def on_exit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.consuming = False
        self.called_back_count = 0

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.horizontal = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.horizontal.Add(self.textbox, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer_vertical = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer_vertical.Add(self.horizontal, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer_vertical)

        # Set callback from windows hook procedure to our python code
        dll_name = "FSHooks.dll"
        dll_abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'Win32',
                                                   'Debug', dll_name))
        dll_handle = cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_abspath)
        self.callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int)
        self.callback = self.callback_type(self.callback_from_c)

        dll_handle.Init()
        dll_handle.SetCallback(self.callback)
        # TODO - Release the hooks when window closes

        # Register the hook
        # We want to pass dll_handle.HookProc
        # which looks like:
        # extern "C" FSHOOKS_API LRESULT HookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

        hookproc_type = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_void_p))


        hook_id = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, pointer,
                                                  win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)




    def callback_from_c(self, number):
        self.textbox.AppendText('Called back from C: {}'.format(number))
```

If you scroll to the part that says '# Register the hook' that is where I am stuck. The pointer variable is not setup and I have no idea what to put there. I've kind of just guess my way through from looking at python examples of SetWindowsHookEx on the same thread rather than from a dll, on Stackoverflow.

Note - I am aware the pyHook library exists, but it is not working correctly in some cases, so I want to try this route myself.

Comment: There's ridiculously too much code. Please check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and create one.

Answer (score 1):

I got the callback working and the hook registered with the following code:

```
# Set callback from windows hook procedure to our python code
dll_name = "FSHooks.dll"
dll_abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'Win32',
                                           'Debug', dll_name))
dll_handle = cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_abspath)
self.callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_bool)
self.callback = self.callback_type(self.callback_from_c)

dll_handle.Init()
dll_handle.SetCallback(self.callback)
# TODO - Release the hooks when window closes

# Register the hook
dll_handle.HookProc.argtypes = (c_int, wintypes.WPARAM, wintypes.LPARAM)
hook_proc_pointer = dll_handle.HookProc
self.hook_id = windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExA(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, hook_proc_pointer,
                                               win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)
```

It appears you can just take the attribute that is the name of the function in the dll and it accepts it as a pointer argument. I had to set the argument types and it worked.